# Unexpected results when star enabled

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I have an index that looks like this:

```
index user_core
{
  source = user_core_0
  path = ...
  charset-type = utf-8
  min_infix_length = 3
  enable_star = 1
}
```

We escape and wrap all of our searches in asterisks. Every so often, we'll come across a
very strange case in which something such as the following happens:

Search: mocuddles

Results: All users with nicknames containing "yellowstone".

This behavior seems unpredictable, but will happen every time on terms it does effect.

I've been told that there's no real way to debug Sphinx indexes. Is this true? Is there
any sort of "explain query" functionality?

Comment: It looks like you're using Thinking Sphinx (as you've tagged this question with it, and the index name looks like it's generated by TS, but you haven't said that explicitly). Can you share the index definition for your model? Also, the SphinxQL queries appear in the Rails logs, so they may hold a clue too.

Comment: What version of sphinx, and do you have a dict=... in the index defintion? Sounds like this might be a hash collision, if so, using a 64bit version of sphinx might help, or changing to dict=keywords (but only worth doing if recent version of sphinx (star queries on old versions can be really slow)

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed at this point that these are instances of CRC32 hash collisions. Bummer.

Comment: dict=keywords should fix things then (add `dict: keywords` to each environment in config/thinking_sphinx.yml).